# If a (possibly nonconvex) pentagon tiles the plane, can it do so periodically?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, tiling, tessellations

From the [classification of monohedral tilings with convex pentagons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_tiling), we know that all convex pentagons which tile the plane can do so periodically; I'd like to know whether the same result is known to extend to non-convex pentagons. That is, if congruent copies of a pentagon $P$ tile the plane, is there necessarily one such tiling which is composed of a single patch of finitely many tiles, translated periodically in a lattice?

There are unlikely to be any known counterexamples, since the [Einstein problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_problem) remains open, but I am curious whether there exists a proof of this statement - if so, a reference would be appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no complete classification of non-convex, tilable pentagons. In my own search for monohedral tilinga I found many with non-convex pentagons, and compiled their tiles into a list of 17 types. Some of them are pictured on [my site here](https://www.jaapsch.net/tilings/nonconvex.htm) but the explicit list is only in the tiling applet available there. I don't know of any other list of known types of non-convex tilable pentagons. My list is almost certainly incomplete, especially with regard to tiles with 3-isohedral tilings.

Comment: I forgot to say that the tiles I found automatically allow periodic tilings because of the way I found them - I searched for periodic tilings, and then compiled the list of tile types. To answer your question you'd have to generate a complete list of candidate tiles somehow, and then check them for tilings.

Answer (score 1):

Einstein problem is open for the pentagons (Check Rao article), he only 'supposedly' closed it for the case of convex pentagons.

Comment: What is the "Rao article"?

Comment: I assume you are referring to Michaël Rao's 2017 [paper](https://perso.ens-lyon.fr/michael.rao/publi/penta.pdf), with which I am familiar. I agree that this particular paper does not resolve the title question, but I don't see why this means the problem is necessarily open.

Comment: As a summary, the proof for the case of convex polygons was by exhibiting a periodic tilling for each tile which can tile the plane, to extend it to non convex pentagons first you need to find all non convex pentagons (polygons in general) which can tessellate the plane which is an open problem (just the case for polyiamonds and polyominoes is hard enough) solving what you ask would solve Einsteing tilling problem

Comment: I agree that *using Rao's approach* to this problem would require classifying all nonconvex tiling pentagons, but why do we have to use that approach? There are general results about certain families of tiles having periodic tilings if they tile at all, e.g. any polyomino under translation. I also know that a *negative* answer would resolve the Einstein problem, which is why I'm wondering about the existence of positive results. I stated this in my question.